# Comparing two doubles in c++ not yielding correct result

Tags: c++, comparison, double, equality

I have two doubles, a and b, in C++ that should be equal but for some reason are not being treated as such. The following code:

```
cout << a << "==" << b << ": " << (a == b) << endl;
```

is outputting

```
0.5 == 0.5: 0
```

Any ideas why this is resolving to false?

Comment: Try this `cout << a << "-" << b << " = " << (a-b) << endl;` and see what you get.

Comment: Seriously, this has been addressed literally hundreds, if not thousands of times here.  Just for a change of pace:  http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/floating-point-arith.html

Comment: Ahh, that must be it. I get "0.5 - 0.5 = 2.22045e-016"

Comment: @user3358762:  Note that 0.5 does yield an exact representation in binary digits (0.1 in binary).  So in your example, you must have computed a and b to be 0.5, but instead got an approximation.  Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: Yes, a was calculated and could be an approximation while b was set to .5;  Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid errors when comparing decimals it might be useful to use a function:

```
bool AreSame(double a, double b)
{
    return fabs(a - b) < EPSILON;
}
```

where EPSILON could be represented by a small number such as `.001`

grabbed from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333/most-effective-way-for-float-and-double-comparison) question.

EDIT: by including `<limits>` one could use `std::numeric_limits<double>::epsilon()`

Comment: absolute is fine but relative comparison rocks too : e.g : `abs(a - b) <= (atol + rtol * abs(b))`

Comment: @Kiwi there are a **lot** of possible solutions to this question, you're right. I just picked one that looked simple to understand